# Unclear on error message in upload from pandas to Google BigQuery table

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

***Situation***

I'm trying to upload a pandas dataframe of Twitter API data to a table in BigQuery.

Here's my dataframe prep code from Google Colab notebook:

```
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-language
!pip install pandas-gbq -U

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))

import os

# Imports Credential File:
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "pp-004a-d61bf3451d85.json"
print("Service Account Key: {}".format(os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]))

!pip install --upgrade tweepy

# VARIABLES

interval = "15"
start = '2022-04-07'
end = '2022-04-12'

# Tweepy
searchQ = '(max muncy) -is:retweet lang:en'
intval_tw = "{}T".format(interval)
start_tw = '{}T00:00:00Z'.format(start)
end_tw   = '{}T23:59:59Z'.format(end)

# index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
# D = calendar day frequency, H = hourly frequency, T, min = minutely frequency

# Library installs

import tweepy
# from twitter_authentication import bearer_token
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import numpy as np

bearer_token = "BEARER_TOKEN"


client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# NEED TO ENSURE HAVE ALL PARAMETERS
gathered_tweets = []
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
                                 query = searchQ,
                                 user_fields = ['name', 'description', 'username', 'profile_image_url', 'url', 'pinned_tweet_id', 'verified', 'created_at', 'location', 'public_metrics', 'entities'],
                                 tweet_fields = ['public_metrics', 'created_at','lang', 'attachments', 'context_annotations', 'conversation_id', 'entities', 'geo', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'possibly_sensitive', 'referenced_tweets', 'reply_settings', 'source'],
                                 media_fields = ['duration_ms', 'media_key', 'preview_image_url', 'type', 'url', 'height', 'width', 'public_metrics'],
                                 expansions = ['author_id', 'attachments.media_keys', 'entities.mentions.username', 'geo.place_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'referenced_tweets.id', 'referenced_tweets.id.author_id'],
                                 start_time = start_tw,
                                 end_time = end_tw,
                              max_results=100):
    time.sleep(1)
    gathered_tweets.append(response)



result = []
user_dict = {}
# Loop through each response object
for response in gathered_tweets:
  # Take all of the users, and put them into a dictionary of dictionaries with the info we want to keep
  for user in response.includes['users']:
      user_dict[user.id] = {'username': user.username,
                            'created_at': user.created_at,
                            'location': user.location,
                            'verified': user.verified,
                            'name': user.name,
                            'description': user.description,
                            'url': user.url,
                            'profile_image_url': user.profile_image_url,
                            'pinned_tweet': user.pinned_tweet_id,
                            'entities': user.entities,
                            'followers': user.public_metrics['followers_count'],
                            'total_tweets': user.public_metrics['tweet_count'],
                            'following': user.public_metrics['following_count'],
                            'listed': user.public_metrics['listed_count'],
                            'tweets': user.public_metrics['tweet_count']
                            }
  for tweet in response.data:
      # For each tweet, find the author's information
      author_info = user_dict[tweet.author_id]
      # Put all of the information we want to keep in a single dictionary for each tweet
      result.append({'author_id': tweet.author_id,
                   'username': author_info['username'],
                   'name': author_info['name'],
                   'author_followers': author_info['followers'],
                   'author_following': author_info['following'],
                   'author_tweets': author_info['tweets'],
                   'author_description': author_info['description'],
                   'author_url': author_info['url'],
                   'profile_image_url': author_info['profile_image_url'],
                   #'pinned_tweet': author_info['pinned_tweet_id'], https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets
                   #'total_tweets': author_info['tweet_count'],
                   #'listed_count': author_info['listed_count'],
                   'entities': author_info['entities'],
                   'verified': author_info['verified'],
                   'account_created_at': author_info['created_at'],
                   'text': tweet.text,
                   'created_at': tweet.created_at,
                   'lang': tweet.lang,
                   'tweet_id': tweet.id,
                   'retweets': tweet.public_metrics['retweet_count'],
                   'replies': tweet.public_metrics['reply_count'],
                   'likes': tweet.public_metrics['like_count'],
                   'quotes': tweet.public_metrics['quote_count'],
                   'replied': tweet.in_reply_to_user_id,
                   'sensitive': tweet.possibly_sensitive,
                   'referenced_tweets': tweet.referenced_tweets,
                   'reply_settings': tweet.reply_settings,
                   'source': tweet.source
                   #'video_views': tweet.public_metrics['view_count']
                   })

dfTW00 = pd.DataFrame(result)

dfTW01 = dfTW00

# Create 'engagement' metric
dfTW01['engagement'] = dfTW01['retweets'] + dfTW01['replies'] + dfTW01['likes'] + dfTW01['quotes']

# Add 'tweets' column with value of 1
dfTW01['tweets'] = 1

# Engagement Rate calc
dfTW01['eng_rate'] = (dfTW01['tweets'] / dfTW01['engagement'])

# Add twitter link
dfTW01['base_url'] = 'https://twitter.com/twitter/status/'
# base_url = 'https://twitter.com/twitter/status/'
dfTW01['tweet_link'] = dfTW01['base_url'] + dfTW01['tweet_id'].astype(str)

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import language_v1

# Instantiates a client
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()


def get_sentiment(text):
    # The text to analyze
    document = language_v1.Document(
        content=text,
        type_=language_v1.types.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT
    )

    # Detects the sentiment of the text
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(
        request={"document": document}
    ).document_sentiment

    return sentiment


dfTW01["sentiment"] = dfTW01["text"].apply(get_sentiment)

dfTW02 = dfTW01['sentiment'].astype(str).str.split(expand=True)
dfTW02

dfTW03 = pd.merge(dfTW01, dfTW02, left_index=True, right_index=True)

dfTW03.rename(columns = {1:'magnitude', 3:'score'}, inplace=True)

cols = ['magnitude', 'score']
dfTW03[cols] = dfTW03[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)

def return_status(x):
    if x >= .5:
        return 'Positive'
    elif x <= -.5:
        return 'Negative'
    return 'Neutral'

dfTW03['sentiment2'] = dfTW03['score'].apply(return_status)
```

***What I've tried***

This is what I've used for the upload (I've confirmed the project, dataset and table info are correct):

```
df.to_gbq('004a01.004a-TW-01', 
                 'pp-004a',
                 chunksize=None, 
                 if_exists='append'
                 )
```

***Results***

However, that method is returning this error message:

`TypeError: <' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`

***Assessment***

I've found several posts on SO addressing this, but I'm unable to relate them to my situation. (I thought various datatypes could be uploaded to a BigQuery table.)

Primarily, I'm not clear what the error message means by `'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`.

Any input on what that would be greatly appreciated.

Below are the pandas dtypes in my dataframe if helpful.

***Dataframe dtypes***

Pandas dataframe dtypes:

```
author_id                           int64
username                           object
name                               object
author_followers                    int64
author_following                    int64
author_tweets                       int64
author_description                 object
author_url                         object
profile_image_url                  object
entities                           object
verified                             bool
account_created_at    datetime64[ns, UTC]
text                               object
created_at            datetime64[ns, UTC]
lang                               object
tweet_id                            int64
retweets                            int64
replies                             int64
likes                               int64
quotes                              int64
replied                           float64
sensitive                            bool
referenced_tweets                  object
reply_settings                     object
source                             object
engagement                          int64
tweets                              int64
eng_rate                          float64
base_url                           object
tweet_link                         object
sentiment                          object
0                                  object
magnitude                         float64
2                                  object
score                             float64
sentiment_rating                  float64
sentiment2                         object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole code when you are trying to load your dataframe to BQ? This is to properly replicate your use case.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottB. I've edited my post to include all the code, up near the top in the section *Situation*. Let me know if I can provide anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `to_gbq()` function from Pandas, you may try and use `load_table_from_dataframe()` function from BigQuery library in loading your dataframe to BigQuery.

Please see the below sample python code using `load_table_from_dataframe()`:

```
import datetime

from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas
import pytz

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "my-project.my-dataset.my-table"

records = [
    {
        "title": "The Meaning of Life",
        "release_year": 1983,
        "length_minutes": 112.5,
        "release_date": pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris")
        .localize(datetime.datetime(1983, 5, 9, 13, 0, 0))
        .astimezone(pytz.utc),
        # Assume UTC timezone when a datetime object contains no timezone.
        "dvd_release": datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 22, 7, 0, 0),
    },
    {
        "title": "Monty Python and the Holy Grail",
        "release_year": 1975,
        "length_minutes": 91.5,
        "release_date": pytz.timezone("Europe/London")
        .localize(datetime.datetime(1975, 4, 9, 23, 59, 2))
        .astimezone(pytz.utc),
        "dvd_release": datetime.datetime(2002, 7, 16, 9, 0, 0),
    },
    {
        "title": "Life of Brian",
        "release_year": 1979,
        "length_minutes": 94.25,
        "release_date": pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
        .localize(datetime.datetime(1979, 8, 17, 23, 59, 5))
        .astimezone(pytz.utc),
        "dvd_release": datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 14, 8, 0, 0),
    },
    {
        "title": "And Now for Something Completely Different",
        "release_year": 1971,
        "length_minutes": 88.0,
        "release_date": pytz.timezone("Europe/London")
        .localize(datetime.datetime(1971, 9, 28, 23, 59, 7))
        .astimezone(pytz.utc),
        "dvd_release": datetime.datetime(2003, 10, 22, 10, 0, 0),
    },
]
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
    records,
    # In the loaded table, the column order reflects the order of the
    # columns in the DataFrame.
    columns=[
        "title",
        "release_year",
        "length_minutes",
        "release_date",
        "dvd_release",
    ],
    # Optionally, set a named index, which can also be written to the
    # BigQuery table.
    index=pandas.Index(
        ["Q24980", "Q25043", "Q24953", "Q16403"], name="wikidata_id"
    ),
)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    # Specify a (partial) schema. All columns are always written to the
    # table. The schema is used to assist in data type definitions.
    schema=[
        # Specify the type of columns whose type cannot be auto-detected. For
        # example the "title" column uses pandas dtype "object", so its
        # data type is ambiguous.
        bigquery.SchemaField("title", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        # Indexes are written if included in the schema by name.
        bigquery.SchemaField("wikidata_id", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
    ],
    # Optionally, set the write disposition. BigQuery appends loaded rows
    # to an existing table by default, but with WRITE_TRUNCATE write
    # disposition it replaces the table with the loaded data.
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Scott B. Greatly appreciate that. I got it working (I think). At least it's not returning an error. But this is what it's returning:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py:560: UserWarning: Pyarrow could not determine the type of columns: entities.
  ", ".join(field.name for field in unknown_type_fields)
Loaded 524 rows and 32 columns to pp-004a.004a01.004a-TW-01`

That's the correct rows and columns count, but there's no data in the datatable. Preview says `There is no data to display.`. Curious if you've ever seen that?

Comment: NM the above, I got it working. Had to remove the `entities` column, but did upload. Actually added to the original data, so I'll need to remove the second upload. Thx for helping me get this working!